# why does not created gdb symbols when I compiled with -g option

Tags: c, linux, unix, gdb

To know how unix command works, I build [procps](https://github.com/soarpenguin/procps-3.0.5).

Here is my procedure,

```
$ git clone git@github.com:soarpenguin/procps-3.0.5.git
$ cd procps-3.0.5
```

- then, I modified Makefile [this line](https://github.com/soarpenguin/procps-3.0.5/blob/master/Makefile#L68)
- just changed option `-g3` => `-g`

**before**

```
CFLAGS := -D_GNU_SOURCE -O2 -g3 -fno-common -ffast-math -I proc
```

**after**

```
CFLAGS := -D_GNU_SOURCE -O2 -g -fno-common -ffast-math -I proc
```

after that

```
   $ mkdir /tmp/sample
   $ make 
   $ sudo make install DESTDIR=/tmp/sample
   install -D --owner 0 --group 0 --mode a=rx --strip top 
   /tmp/sample/usr/bin/top
   $ ls /tmp/sample/usr/bin/ |grep top
   top
```

## Question

Somehow I add `-g` option, gdb can't read symbol, why?
especialy `no debugging symbols found`

```
$ gdb /tmp/sample/usr/bin/top
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-92.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /tmp/sample/usr/bin/top...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

## my environment

```
$ cat /etc/system-release
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

$ gdb -v
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-92.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
```

Comment: You see that the `install` program is using the `--strip` option? That is what stips debug information. Also, `-g3` is just `-g` but with more information added, no need to change that.

Comment: Also, you may need to `make clean` or `make -B` to recompile if you change only the Makefile

Comment: Use `file` to quickly show whether symbols are present.

Answer (score 1):

strip option discards all symbols from object files.  It is used for production objects to be light weight.

To ensure that it is the strip option, run the gdb before installing it.

Answer (score 0):

> `sudo make install DESTDIR=/tmp/sample`

It is very common for `make install` to strip the binaries that are installed.

> `install -D --owner 0 --group 0 --mode a=rx --strip top`

And that's exactly what happened here (note the `--strip` above).

You can either debug the original executable:

```
gdb ./top
```

or debug the installed `/tmp/sample/usr/bin/top` while using the original binary as symbol file:

```
gdb /tmp/sample/usr/bin/top
(gdb) symbol-file ./top
(gdb) run
```

Comment: Thanks! I can attach the built "top" process with gdb! Because of your clear example, I learned how gdb options work. I'll continue to study from the source codes.